# Requests Dialog for websites

Tags: facebook, xfbml

This is related to another question that I had asked [Is fb:multi-friend-selector deprecated?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8712710/is-fbmulti-friend-selector-deprecated).

One suggestion was to use Request Dialogs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

I was reading thru the documentation for Requests Dialog and it has this "If a user clicks 'Accept' on a request, they will be sent to the canvas URL of the application that sent the request".

I want the user to be redirected to my website and not the canvas page. Is this possible? This is possible currently (using xfbml) by using `<fb:req-choice url="mywebsite"/>`. Will xfbml (using request form and req-choice within it) stop working after June?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a redirect on your canvas url to your website.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Lix. Is this the only way (sounds a little hacky to me)

Comment: Very true - but I havent managed to find a different solution...yet...  I'll be happy if someone proves me wrong! :)